# Importing cv2 on Python 2.7 gives error

Tags: python, opencv

When importing cv2 on Python 2.7 I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've downloaded the missing DLLs using dependency walker and added them to the path of cv2.pyd but I had another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be better off with asking this question on Stackoverflow as it is not directly related to a Geographic Information Systems.

Also don't forget to check out possibly related questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls.